# How to capture elements right click context menu in coded UI

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coded-ui-tests, vsix

I need to capture and verify elements in right click context menu. I'm going to test VS extension development project. How can i resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Move the mouse pointer over the context menu then use the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> key combination. (For Visual Studio 2010 it was <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> but Windows 8 userped that combination.) See [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mathew_aniyan/2012/03/12/where-did-wini-go/) and [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mathew_aniyan/2010/01/12/coded-ui-test-tip-of-the-day-1-wini-to-locate-controls/).